# Multiple Selects in Single Query

Tags: mysql

I'm hoping someone fluent in MySQL will be able to assist me with this. I'm trying to do a select on a select on a select, but the query doesn't seem to want to complete. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT 
    product as pid, 
    leg_name as name, 
    dimensions as dims 
FROM 
    pmaint 
WHERE 
    product in (
        SELECT product 
        FROM qb_export_items_attributes
        WHERE attribute_name = 'Z' 
        AND product in (
                SELECT product
                FROM pmainT
                WHERE type_ID = (
                        SELECT ID
                        FROM type
                        WHERE SOFTCARTCATEGORY = 'End Table Legs'
                    )
                )
        AND attribute_value <= 3.5
    )
```

Comment: 1) what do you mean by "doesn't want to complete?" 2) what have you tried to make it work? (eg have you tried each individual select to see if one of them is broken?)

Comment: Why subqueries and not joins?

Comment: @AndrewMcGivery If I was drinking a coffee, I would have spat it all over my screen

Comment: @Phil It turns out I was lied to at some point along the way. Just did some research and now I am rather embarrassed... Thank goodness comments have a delete function. :P

Comment: @TarynEast So I have tried each individual select, and the two inner selects work without issue. When I add on the last select, the query just sits there. In my phpMyAdmin interface, it just sits at the screen stating loading.

Comment: @MattBall I'm not familiar with how joins work. In this case, I am trying to select the Product ID Number, Product Name, and Product Dimensions from the pmaint table. The Product must have a type_ID value equal to the ID for SOFTCARTCATEGORY = 'End Table Legs' which is obtained through the innermost select query and it must have a width of <= 3.5. Unfortunately I don't have direct control of the SQL data as I have to work with an existing company's database schema.

Comment: If it's a really huge number of products.... it might just take a reeeeally long time to return to you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use INNER JOINs instead of IN subqueries

UPD: I've edited this query according you comment. the first JOIN subquery output all `product` where both attributes exists and true.

```
SELECT 
    pmaint.product as pid, 
    pmaint.leg_name as name, 
    pmaint.dimensions as dims 
FROM 
    pmaint 
JOIN (select product from qb_export_items_attributes
       where ((attribute_name = 'Z') and (attribute_value <= 3.5))
             OR
             ((attribute_name = 'top_square') and (attribute_value >= 4))
       GROUP BY product HAVING COUNT(*)=2
      ) 

         t1 on (pmaint.product=t1.product )
JOIN type on (pmaint.type_ID=type.ID)
WHERE 
        type.SOFTCARTCATEGORY = 'End Table Legs'
```

Comment: Valex, one other component I forgot to add and I'm hoping you can help with this...

If t1.attribute_name = 'Z' then t1.attribute_value <=3.5.
If t1.attribute_name = 'top_square' then t1.attribute_value >= 4.

Both of these conditions must be true for a single product ID to show up. The data for t1 looks like this.

`  PRODUCT | attribute_name | attribute_value
  1 | Z | 3.5
  1 | top_square | 3
  2 | Z | 2
  2 | top_square | 5
  3 | Z | 5
  3 | top_square | 4`

We should only match for Product ID 2 because both Z <= 3.5 AND top_square >= 4.

Thanks again for your assistance so far

Comment: Replace -- with line breaks. Then the data will look more appropriate in tabular format. --

PRODUCT | attribute_name | attribute_value --
1 | Z | 3.5 --
1 | top_square | 3 --
2 | Z | 2 --
2 | top_square | 5 --
3 | Z | 5 --
3 | top_square | 4 --

We should only match for Product ID 2 because both Z <= 3.5 AND top_square >= 4.

Comment: Valex, you are wonderful! Thank you very very much. You have been most helpful!